# SELECT from multiple tables with the same structure

Tags: mysql

Hi and sorry in advance if this question was asked before, i could not find any in Google.

I am searching a solution for my issue;
I have multiple report tables with the same structure (data is coming from different sources and i had to split the tables),
I need to perform a `SELECT` statement that will fetch the needed data from all of those tables but i am also trying to apply a `GROUP BY` from the collective result of said tables.

For example: When applying a `GROUP BY` for date for each table it will group any specific table by its date, but when merging all of the results together i am left with multiple grouped tables and not a single result with the necessary groupings.

I know how to perform a `GROUP BY` for a specific table but i have no idea how can i perform it without the touch of any complicated PHP scripts.

I do not have any examples of what i did because i could not think of any ideas so far.

A PHP script will do the trick too but i prefer it to be in plain SQL.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Answer (score 1):

Combining multiple tables into 1 set of data is usually done with `UNION` , then you can use the entire data as 1 set of data :

```
SELECT <Col1>,<Col2>,SUM(<Col3>) as Sum_Col_3
FROM(
    SELECT <Col1>,<Col2>,<Col3> FROM TableA 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT <Col1>,<Col2>,<Col3> FROM TableB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT <Col1>,<Col2>,<Col3> FROM TableC) t
GROUP BY <Col1>,<Col2>
```