# select from multiple tables with the same column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to select the same columns from different tables that look the same
(daily tables).

I saw this [SELECT from multiple tables with the same structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341822/select-from-multiple-tables-with-the-same-structure) answer but if I'm going according to this I'm ending up with a huge query.

this code is similar to what I have, according to answer above I need to do the following:

```
select a, b, c
from (
    select a, b, c, d, e from hourly.16
    union all
    select a, b, c, d, e from hourly.15
)
```

isn't there an option to do something like:

```
select a, b, c
from (
    select a, b, c, d, e from (hourly.16 union all hourly.15)
)
```

so I won't end up with huge queries?

Comment: Why not `SELECT *`? Or select from `hourly.*` instead (look up the documentation for wildcard tables)?

Comment: I want to select from a range of tables, selecting from hourly.* will generate a query that will scan huge amount of data (irrelevant data)

Comment: That's why you filter on `_TABLE_SUFFIX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT a, b, c
FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c, d, e 
    FROM `project.hourly.*`
    WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '15' AND '16'
)
```

Above is assuming that `hourly` is your dataset